# CSS naming guidelines

Tags: css

I was reading this:

"Guideline Number 7:  Try to avoid using unecessary classes and IDs.

So, now that we’re keeping our hooks to a minimum, it’s time for our next step in quality over quantity: naming. We want to avoid names that imply presentational aspects. Otherwise, if we name something right-col, it’s entirely possible that the CSS would change and our “right-col” would end up actually being displayed on the left side of our page. That could lead to some confusion in the future, so it’s best that we avoid these types of presentational naming schemes."

So what do I call them if not right-col and not presentational?!?!

Comment: Please strive for a better question topic next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discuss this very topic in [*"How to Develop with CSS"*](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector). What you call it depends on the content. Maybe "sidebar" or "links" or "extra".

Answer (score 1):

any naming technique has advantages and disadvantages...try to find a way that help you more in your work, and make well commented css files.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than naming things after their presentation name them for their function, or purpose. Also, try to use a coherent page structure so far as possible, and use the CSS cascade to access/target elements.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it conveys meaning for the html structure and other developers can understand well it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

check out [960.gs](http://960.gs) using that gridsystem will save a lot of time, trying to figure out the best naming scheme.

Answer (score 0):

[NCSS](http://ncss.io) Sheets is a naming convention and guideline for semantic CSS: [CSS class naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927193/css-class-naming-convention/20253304#20253304)